# Load jboss-ejb-client.properties from local file system and set IntialContext for jndi lookup

Tags: java, spring, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

Unable to set the jboss-ejb-client.properties in the environment of spring application, As it is loaded from the local file system

```
jboss-ejb-client.properties:

remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=10.203.67.52
remote.connection.default.port=8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.connection.default.username=****
remote.connection.default.password=****
```

Below is the file where jboss-ejb-client.properties is loaded, This file is not overriding the spring jar (jboss-ejb-client.properties) file

Wanted to dynamically pass the server "hostaddress" to the application via local filesystem property file

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({
      @PropertySource(value = "file:${ART_CONFIG_DIR}/jboss-ejb-client.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)

public class SynchronizerJobConfiguration {......
```

Is there any way to load and set jboss-ejb-client.properties file into spring run time environment

Workaround solution I used is getResourceStream(jboss-ejb-client property file)

Setting the property for the host worked.

Need some clean approach to override properties

Comment: Is the `ART_CONFIG_DIR` set as environment variable?

Comment: Yes it is in the environment (  local filesystem path)

Comment: Isn't it loaded or isn't it overriding? As those are different things

Comment: Its not overriding the src/resources/jboss-ejb-client.properties

Comment: That can be a ordering issue...

Comment: During runtime whether we can change the env:remote.connection.default.host=ipAddress ?

Comment: Changing the property at runtime isn't going to change anything... Beans are created at startup and remain in that state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92362/discussion-between-syed-mazreena-and-m-deinum).